# Best way to implement a smooth spinner on android

Tags: android, multithreading, performance

I have troubles getting a smooth loading animation (without laggs/stuttering) done on android.
I am using an AsyncTask to fetch data asynchronously, but it seems the UI thread is influenced by it.
For my spinner (loading indicator) I am using a png icon and I am rotating it via Animation:

```
Animation mRotateAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.rotate);
progressBar.startAnimation(mRotateAnim);
```

While loading data the spinner start lagging. It gets even worse when I am trying to load stuff in a webview -> loading animation freezes completely for up to 3 seconds.

I am using a Galaxy S3 for testing (multi core!).

Anyone has a solution for that?

Comment: If my answer doesn't help please post more code so that we can see what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

Don't you want to use the standard Android spinner, it should give you better performance. If not look at [this](http://www.hrupin.com/2011/09/how-to-make-custom-indeterminate-progressbar-in-android-or-how-to-change-progressbar-style-or-color) link for creating a custom `ProgressBar` else have a look at my layout below.

I specify my `WebView` in my main `RelativeLayout` and my `ProgressBar` in the same layout. As soon as the layout is loaded my `ProgressBar` is shown on top and when the `WebView` content is loaded I hide the `LinearLayout` my `ProgressBar` is defined in.

This works perfectly for me on my HTC One X

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/browserView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</WebView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/browserProgressLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/widget_background_dark"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/content_padding" >

        <TextView
            style="@style/ListLargeText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/bus_loader_text"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/terminal_text_color" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/browserProgress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

You should be able to use a normal `ProgressDialog` without any performance issues. This is actually the better way to do it because this will be styled to the theme you applied to your application.

```
ProgressDialog progDailog = ProgressDialog.show(_context,
                progressString, "Loading please wait...",
                true);
```

Comment: Yes, I know that there is the standard way of using a progress dialog. But that's not the thing I am interested in.

Comment: Yes I thought you might not be. I'm guessing you're also doing it in a similar way as in the link I posted?

Comment: No I am not. Thanks for the link, I will give it a try. Still I think the root of the problem is not the implementation of the spinner, but a thread issue...

Comment: We also implement a custom spinner that works with a very complex fragment based app. We have some lag but only on the older tablets. On the newer tablets it works smoothly with server interaction, opengl rendering and 5 fragments that run a few different threads. so I don't think your one thread should cause it to lag unless you do something that is very memory intensive.

Comment: did you use a custom ProgressBar or did you just rotate a view (like I did it)?

Comment: Rotated the progress bar with a animation